# strange warnings for transformable attribute

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I was using transformable attributes and everything work fine instead of those warnings:

```
15.10.11 22:14:07,191 cdtool: CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'ArrayToDataTransformer' was found for attribute 'directions' on entity 'DatabaseConnections'
15.10.11 22:14:07,191 cdtool: CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'ArrayToDataTransformer' was found for attribute 'updateChoices' on entity 'DatabaseConnections'
15.10.11 22:14:07,193 cdtool: CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'ArrayToDataTransformer' was found for attribute 'testingResult' on entity 'DestinationsListWeBuy'
```

may anybody tell how to move out this warning.
for sure, everything is correct, attribute is optional, transformable.
bellow is a class implementation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ArrayToDataTransformer : NSValueTransformer {

}

@end



#import "ArrayToDataTransformer.h"


@implementation ArrayToDataTransformer

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSData class];
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    //Take an NSArray archive to NSData
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
    return data;
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    //Take NSData unarchive to NSArray 
    NSArray *array = (NSArray*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
    return array;
}

@end
```

Comment: I want to practise TDD. Is there a way that I can catch this warning and make assertions to ensure the presence of such a transformer?

Comment: did u get the answer. I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Before you can call a custom transformer you have to register it with:

```
+[NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:forName:]
```

… otherwise, the runtime doesn't know the transformer exist.

Comment: i make configuration in core data UI config. Where is i have to place this setValueTransformer peace of code.